# What is the correct way to combine multiple animations with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

This is what I have written as my animation - however it applies to all my HTML elements with this animation at the same time instead of each one as its own animation process.

What am I missing?

```
// JavaScript Document
          $(document).ready(function(){ 
               $('.learnmore').mouseenter(function(){
                  $(".cover").stop().animate({top:'150px'},{ duration:160});
                });

                $('.learnmore').mouseleave(function(){
                      $(".cover").stop().delay('2500').animate({top:'300px'},{ duration:160,easing:'easeOutBounce'});
                });


        });
```

Comment: Are you saying that all the `.covers` get animated all once. And you want to animate one after the other.

Comment: @TheSuperTramp Yes. All the .covers get animated when my mouse .mouseenter(s) - my intention is for each .cover to have its own animation process meaning having the .cover animate individually upon .mouseenter. make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see example here. http://jsfiddle.net/robx/VdUuM/3/
Explanations also commented on there with the code.

Comment: @robx Here is a better example of what my problem is. As you'll see all my boxes are being 'animated' when i mouseover. Can you point out where my mistake is? Just so I know where it is. Thanks. 
http://jsfiddle.net/rfuLP/

Comment: I have no idea since I am not seeing anything being animated. But my assumption tells me that it's because you are targeting a class which could be all of many other elements. If you want just that one to animate, and read my comments of explanation at jsfiddle, you would see that $(this) refers to current object mouse is over. If you target, class, all class get animated.

Comment: so as other's mentioned, if you only want certain objects to animate, you will need to find specific object as target.

Comment: try this: $(this).parent().find('.cover').stop().animate({...}) though you seem to have other issues in itself as well or could just be that i am using safari, but i can only view the most bottom "learn more" link

Comment: @robx thank you very much. I got it to work with your help and comments! thanks Rob. Just so i have clear knowledge and better understanding when will i need or have to declare $(this)?

Comment: anytime you use $(this), it refers to whatever you are interacting with (an object interacting itself).

Answer (score 0):

You need more specific CSS in place of $(".cover"). 
Something like

```
$(this).children('.cover')...
```

Or

```
$('.learnmore .cover')...
```